# Goldengate purgeoldextract not working

Tags: oracle-golden-gate

For few months I was dealing this problem. I have a mgr process that should automatically delete processed trail files  . It is working in other servers.

```
PURGEOLDEXTRACTS /ggs/dirdat/AA*, USECHECKPOINTS, MINKEEPHOURS 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found the problem. There is a problem with wildcards.

Put space between star and comma and it works perfectly.

```
PURGEOLDEXTRACTS /ggs/dirdat/AA* , USECHECKPOINTS, MINKEEPHOURS 2
```